# Restkit - Deleting orphaned objects with the same URL path

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit, restkit-0.20

I had read this document but it does not show any example solution for this problem:
[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation Class Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJBC7.png)

I want to use several addFetchRequestBlock methods to remove orphaned objects from the same API call I am making. When I remove some record in server side, the parent objects work fine. However, Restkit does not remove those nested objects.

---

My API JSON output - /regions :

(Region has many Districts and Buildings)

(District has many Buildings)

```
{
"regions": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "region A",
        "districts": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "region_id": 1,
                "name": "district A",
                "buildings": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "region_id": 1,
                        "district_id": 1,
                        "name": "building A"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 2,
                        "region_id": 1,
                        "district_id": 1,
                        "name": "building B"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "region_id": 1,
                "name": "district B",
                "buildings": []
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "region_id": 1,
                "name": "district C",
                "buildings": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "region B",
        "districts": [
            {
                "id": 4,
                "region_id": 2,
                "name": "district D",
                "buildings": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "region_id": 2,
                        "district_id": 4,
                        "name": "building C"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "region_id": 1,
                "name": "district E",
                "buildings": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

---

My core data model:

[image]

---

My Object Mapping and addFetchRequestBlock:

(I am trying to use 3 addFetchRequestBlock for deleting orphaned objects; Region, District and Building when the URL path is called)

(1, Restkit deletes those orphaned Region objects correctly)

(2. The deleted objects in District and Building are still in client side)

```
- (void) setupRegionMappings
{

// Object Mappings
// -------------------------------------------------
// Get RKObjectManager singleton
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];



// Get default managed object store
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore];

// Create the RKObjectMapping mapping for our object class:
RKEntityMapping *buildingMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Building class])
                                                  inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];



[buildingMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                 @"id": @"buildingID",
                                                 @"district_id": @"districtID",
                                                 @"region_id": @"regionID",
                                                 @"name": @"name",
                                                 @"name_zh": @"nameZh",
                                                 @"name_cn": @"nameCn",
                                                 @"name_en": @"nameEn"
                                                 }];

// Identify the object in database
buildingMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"buildingID"];


// Establish the connection for relation between attributes in core data
[buildingMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"region" connectedBy:@{@"regionID": @"regionID"}];
[buildingMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"district" connectedBy:@{@"districtID": @"districtID"}];
[buildingMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"shops" connectedBy:@{@"buildingID": @"buildingID"}];



// Create the RKObjectMapping mapping for our object class:
RKEntityMapping *districtMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([District class])
                                                  inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];



[districtMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                 @"id": @"districtID",
                                                 @"region_id": @"regionID",
                                                 @"name": @"name",
                                                 @"name_zh": @"nameZh",
                                                 @"name_cn": @"nameCn",
                                                 @"name_en": @"nameEn"
                                                 }];

// Identify the object in database
districtMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"districtID"];


// Establish the connection for relation between attributes in core data
[districtMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"region" connectedBy:@{@"regionID": @"regionID"}];
[districtMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"buildings" connectedBy:@{@"districtID": @"districtID"}];
[districtMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"shops" connectedBy:@{@"districtID": @"districtID"}];


// Define the relationship mapping on json
[districtMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"buildings"
                                                                                toKeyPath:@"buildings"
                                                                              withMapping:buildingMapping]];


// Create the RKObjectMapping mapping for our object class:
RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Region class])
                                               inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"id": @"regionID",
                                              @"name": @"name",
                                              @"name_zh": @"nameZh",
                                              @"name_cn": @"nameCn",
                                              @"name_en": @"nameEn"
                                              }];
// Identify the object in database
mapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"regionID"];

// Establish the connection for relation between attributes in core data
[mapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"districts" connectedBy:@{@"regionID": @"regionID"}];
[mapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"buildings" connectedBy:@{@"regionID": @"regionID"}];
[mapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"shops" connectedBy:@{@"regionID": @"regionID"}];

// Define the relationship mapping on json
[mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"districts"
                                                                        toKeyPath:@"districts"
                                                                      withMapping:districtMapping]];




// The mapping will be triggered if a response status code is anything in 2xx
NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful);

// Put it all together in response descriptor (for a GET request method)
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                   pathPattern:@"regions"
                                                                                       keyPath:@"regions"
                                                                                   statusCodes:statusCodes];


// Add response descriptor to our shared manager
[manager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];





// Routings
// -------------------------------------------------
// Route for list of type objects
RKRoute *indexRoute = [RKRoute routeWithName:@"regions" pathPattern:@"regions" method:RKRequestMethodGET];
indexRoute.shouldEscapePath = YES;


// Add defined routes to the Object Manager router
[manager.router.routeSet addRoutes:@[indexRoute]];



// Making Consistency
// -------------------------------------------------
// Deleting orphaned objects
// Define Fetch request to trigger on specific url
[manager addFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSURL *URL) {

    // Create a path matcher
    RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher = [RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern:@"regions"];

    // Dictionary to store request arguments
    NSDictionary *argsDict = nil;

    // Match the URL with pathMatcher and retrieve arguments
    BOOL match = [pathMatcher matchesPath:[URL relativePath] tokenizeQueryStrings:NO parsedArguments:&argsDict];


    // If url matched, create NSFetchRequest
    if (match) {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [Region MR_requestAllSortedBy:@"regionID" ascending:YES];
        return fetchRequest;
    }

    return nil;
}];


[manager addFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSURL *URL) {

    // Create a path matcher
    RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher = [RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern:@"regions"];

    // Dictionary to store request arguments
    NSDictionary *argsDict = nil;

    // Match the URL with pathMatcher and retrieve arguments
    BOOL match = [pathMatcher matchesPath:[URL relativePath] tokenizeQueryStrings:NO parsedArguments:&argsDict];

    // If url matched, create NSFetchRequest
    if (match) {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [District MR_requestAllSortedBy:@"districtID" ascending:YES];
        return fetchRequest;
    }

    return nil;
}];


[manager addFetchRequestBlock:^NSFetchRequest *(NSURL *URL) {
    // Create a path matcher
    RKPathMatcher *pathMatcher = [RKPathMatcher pathMatcherWithPattern:@"regions"];

    // Dictionary to store request arguments
    NSDictionary *argsDict = nil;

    // Match the URL with pathMatcher and retrieve arguments
    BOOL match = [pathMatcher matchesPath:[URL relativePath] tokenizeQueryStrings:NO parsedArguments:&argsDict];

    // If url matched, create NSFetchRequest
    if (match) {
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [Building MR_requestAllSortedBy:@"buildingID" ascending:YES];
        return fetchRequest;
    }

    return nil;
}];


}
```

How can I sync these nested entities when I am making the same API call once?
Great Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one fetch request block will be used. The correct approach to solve your problem would be to use the Core Data deletion rules on your relationships such that a deletion of a `Region` results in a `cascade` deletion of the associated `District`s and `Building`s.

The fetch request blocks you show in the question delete everything that wasn't received in the last request. Because you are using `identificationAttributes` and 1:many relationships it is possible for the received response to reconnect existing `District`s and `Building`s to a new `Region` before the `Region` is deleted, so the cascade would not apply to them.

Answer (score 0):

After I delete those addConnectionForRelationship functions. It works perfectly...

Comment: Removing `addConnectionForRelationship` just means you aren't connecting the relationships, it doesn't delete anything from the data store.